# Facebook test users with checkin details?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, testing

I have created an app and have set up a few test users. My aim is to create posts with check-in to specific places say "Disney store xyz street" or " Waffle house yz street" but currently its allowing me to only add checkins for specific cities.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is allowing? We have no idea what you are doing

Comment: edit: 

I am trying to make an app that get users posts information. I need  the places where user has made check-in. Check-ins at local businesses etc. specifically. And for populating the dummy data in the dummy test profiles I am trying to add a status with check in "Racing Car XYZ place, NYC". This place is an actual place, and it doesnt show up, while NYC, or city etc are showing up in the drop down menu.

Comment: That doesn't explain what you are doing

Comment: You can only specify the place via the id of an existing Facebook page. Using arbitrary address/location data is not possible.